# Abstract class with nested class, is this possible?

Tags: java

If I write an abstract class, then nest a class in the abstract class, will I have access to its methods in any subclasses of the abstract class? I cannot find the answer anywhere..

Comment: Could you provide a structural example? not sure if you mean class A is abstract, class B is inner class of A (extends A? static?), and class C extends A external to A? or extends B? Please be a little more specific.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course, access modifiers on inner classes obey the same rules as on fields and methods.   It does not matter whether your class is abstract or concrete, as long as the nested class is either `public`, `protected` or the subclass is in the same package and the inner class is package private (default access modifier), the subclass will have access to it.

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {

    // all subclasses have access to these classes
    public class PublicInner {}
    protected class ProtectedInner {}

    // subclasses in the same package have access to this class
    class PackagePrivateInner {}

    // subclasses do not have access to this class
    private class PrivateClass {}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Abstract {
    modifier1 class Nested { modifier2 int i = 0; }
    Abstract() {
        Nested n = new Nested();
        n.i = 1;
    }
}

class Sub extends Abstract {
    Sub() {
        Nested n = new Nested();
       // have access as long you not choose "private"
       // for `modifier1` or `modifier2`:
        n.i = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the nested class is at least protected, we can access its methods (as long as the methods are public or we are in the same package and they are not private).

But you could have tried this out yourself easily :-)